# Why are the two code snippets not working as they should?

Tags: python

The **data.txt** file looks like this:

```
jim@gmail.com: hello123
malik@gmail.com: helloworld
jim24@gmail.com: hell123
```

The following code *extracts information from **data.txt** file* and uses it to **deny or grant the access** to the user based on the username and password typed.

```
current_attempts = 0
total_attempts = 3
data_file = open('data.txt', 'r')
read_datafile = data_file.read()
while current_attempts < total_attempts:
    username = input("Enter Email: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")

    if username in read_datafile and password in read_datafile:
        print(f"""Access Granted. Welcome {username}!
""")
        break

    elif username not in read_datafile and password not in read_datafile:
        current_attempts += 1
        print(f"""Access Denied. You have {total_attempts - current_attempts} chances left!
""")
```

The aforementioned code *only checks if the typed username and password is in the **data.txt** file but doesn't compare it* as is the **difference** between: `in` and `==`. For example, if I only type `jim` in username and `hello` in password, then also the user is granted the access.
To avoid that, I have already prepared **another code snippet** that **could help** to compare the two data(s) and only grant user the access when the two data's perfectly match each other:

```
for line in data_file.readlines():
    break_line = line.index(':')
    _email = line[:break_line]
    _password = line[(break_line + 2):len(line)]
```

When I **merge** the two snippets, I get this:

```
current_attempts = 0
total_attempts = 3
data_file = open('data.txt', 'r')
while current_attempts < total_attempts:
    username = input("Enter Email: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")

    for line in data_file.readlines():
        break_line = line.index(':')
        _email = line[:break_line]
        _password = line[(break_line + 2):len(line)]

        if username == _email and password == _password:
            print(f"""Access Granted. Welcome {username}!
""")
            break

        elif username != _email and password != _password:
            current_attempts += 1
            print(f"""Access Denied. You have {total_attempts - current_attempts} chances left!
""")
```

Even after this, I don't see my code running as I expected it to be.

Comment: Put the data in a dictionary: `d = {}; for line in f: uname,pw = line.strip().split(':'); d[uname] = pw.strip()`  Then check `if d.get(username,None) == password:...`

Comment: Store the email/password items in a `dict` and use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) to store it on disk. Then you can just look up the email in the `dict` and check it has the right password.

Comment: Thank you but how does the ```.strip()```, ```.split()``` and ```.get()``` method works, I am a beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to build up the username and passwords outside of the loop. Then you can check the username and password against the dict and count failed attempts.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    authdict = {}
    for line in f:
        username, password = line.split(': ')
        authdict[username.strip()] = password.strip()
```

Then

```
while current_attempts < total_attempts:
    username = input("Enter Email: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
    if authdict.get(username) == password:
        # you are authorized, break loop
        break
    # otherwise do what you need to do for unauthorized
```

Comment: Thank you but how does the ```.strip()```, ```.split()``` and ```.get()``` method works?         Also how the heck my code is running properly with this line ```if authdict.get(username) == password:```, how does that work as well?

Comment: strip and split are built-in python methods on strings. The documentation is at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split

Comment: Get is a built-in method for dictionary. It gets the value associated with a key or returns None. The documentation is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get. You want to use get because it will not raise an error if the key (here, user) is not in the dict.

Comment: Got it. That is a really useful method. I will  be using that frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used list , I prefer handle it with List too.

First of all you have to define 2 empty `list` before your outer `for`

```
email = []
passwords = []
```

and then in `for` you have to `.append()` each new email and passwords to their `list` , like below :

```
        break_line = line.index(':')
        email.append(line[:break_line])
        passwords.append( line[(break_line + 2):len(line)])
```

and the compelete code look like below :

```
data_file = open('./data.txt', 'r')
email = []
passwords = []
for line in data_file.readlines():
        break_line = line.index(':')
        email.append(line[:break_line])
        passwords.append( line[(break_line + 2):len(line)])
```

and if you `print(email)` the output is :

```
['jim@gmail.com', 'malik@gmail.com', 'jim24@gmail.com']
```

and now your first code for checking can work , what I mean is You are now able to use `in` for each username and passwords

```
if username in read_datafile and password in read_datafile:
       print(f"""Access Granted. Welcome {username}!
```

because We made a `list` that contain the email and a `list` for password

Answer (score 0):

```
import getpass
# this is what you'll get when you read the text file
flrd = "jim@gmail.com: hello123\nmalik@gmail.com: helloworld\njim24@gmail.com: hell123"

#use the flat string to create a dictionary by splitting the string by row, then by :
#the dictionary returns the password given the username
pdct = {u:p 
for pr in flrd.split('\n')
    for u,p in [pr.split(': ')]
    }
total_attempts = 3
for i in range(total_attempts): 
    # get the username
    username = input("Enter Email: ")
    #get the password
    password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password: ")
    try:
        #check if the user input matches the password.
        #if username is not in the dictionary, except will catch a KeyError
        if pdct[username] == password:
            # if a valid username and password are entered, break the loop
            print(f'Welcome {username}')
            break
        else:
            #raising a KeyError moves moves the script to the except statement
            #an invalid username is the same as an invalid password
            raise KeyError
    except KeyError:
        print(f'incorrect username or password, {total_attempts - i -1} attempts remaining')
        print(password)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time for me, but it's really hard for me to understand your code snippet, I am just a beginner :(

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks Buddy!